# How do I create a datatable in a simple way?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, datatables, bootstrap-4

How do I create a `datatables`-table? I have a table, but datatables is not working (search table, pagination, dropdown and sort by).

I'm using the CDN-version of CSS and JavaScript for datatables, but it's still not working.

This is my code:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

    <head>
        <!-- Required meta tags -->
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

        <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
        <!-- DATATABLE -->
        <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.18/css/dataTables.bootstrap4.min.css">

        <title>Hello, world!</title>
    </head>

    <body>
        <div class="container fluid">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="offset-2 col-sm-8 mt-2">
                    <table class="table table-hover table-striped table-bordered dataTable" id="isi">
                        <thead>
                            <tr>
                                <th scope="col">#</th>
                                <th scope="col">ID</th>
                                <th scope="col">Lokasi</th>
                            </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody>
                            <tr>
                                <th scope="row">1</th>
                                <td>Mark</td>
                                <td>Otto</td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <th scope="row">2</th>
                                <td>Jacob</td>
                                <td>Thornton</td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <th scope="row">3</th>
                                <td>Larry the Bird</td>
                                <td>@twitter</td>
                            </tr>
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <!-- START SCRIPT -->
        <script type="text/JavaScript">
            $(document).ready(function() {
                $(#isi).dataTable();
            });
        </script>
        <!-- Optional JavaScript -->
        <!-- DATATABLE -->
        <script type="text/JavaScript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.18/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/JavaScript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.18/js/dataTables.bootstrap4.min.js"></script>
        <!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    </body>

</html>
```

I think the problem is my CDN is not working, like link rel stylesheet or script.

Comment: You need to load jquery before dataTables.js and bootstrap.js and using it in `$(document)`. If you check the console, you should see these errors.

Comment: can you show me the code? because i tried and still not working

Answer (score 4, accepted):

jQuery needs to be loaded before Bootstrap and dataTables files as they are dependent upon`$`.

So,

- Move jQuery, popper and bootstrap.js files above the datatables' files
- Add your js code like `$(document).ready()` below this.
- Add quotes around the jquery selector: `$("#isi")`

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

  <head>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <!-- DATATABLE -->
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.18/css/dataTables.bootstrap4.min.css">

    <title>Hello, world!</title>
  </head>

  <body>
    <div class="container fluid">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="offset-2 col-sm-8 mt-2">
          <table class="table table-hover table-striped table-bordered dataTable" id="isi">
            <thead>
              <tr>
                <th scope="col">#</th>
                <th scope="col">ID</th>
                <th scope="col">Lokasi</th>
              </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
              <tr>
                <th scope="row">1</th>
                <td>Mark</td>
                <td>Otto</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <th scope="row">2</th>
                <td>Jacob</td>
                <td>Thornton</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <th scope="row">3</th>
                <td>Larry the Bird</td>
                <td>@twitter</td>
              </tr>
            </tbody>
          </table>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

    <!-- DATATABLE -->
    <script type="text/JavaScript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.18/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/JavaScript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.18/js/dataTables.bootstrap4.min.js"></script>

    <script>

      $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#isi").dataTable();
      });

    </script>

  </body>

</html>
```